# Why python3.7 returns different output than python3.6(anaconda) with re.split()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

```
#test.py
import re

tmp = {'value': 'V-4056366 ', 'bool': False}
def get_split():
    value = str(tmp['value']).strip()
    if value=='':
        return None
    if value.isalnum(): 
        return None
    return re.split(r'[-.]*',value)

print(get_split())
```

If I run the above code with the pre-installed python 3.7 I get the following output (the **output** that I really want to get).

```
[pc@pc-pc PasivicSoftware]$ python3.7 test.py
['', 'V', '', '4', '0', '5', '6', '3', '6', '6', '']
[pc@pc-pc PasivicSoftware]$ which python3.7
/bin/python3.7
```

Now with anaconda 3.6.5:

```
[pc@pc-pc PasivicSoftware]$ python3 test.py
/home/pc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py:212: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
['V', '4056366'][pc@pc-pc PasivicSoftware]
$ which python3
/home/pc/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

**Did python3.7 change the behavior of re.split? If so, how can I get the same output of anaconda (just two elements in a list)**

Comment: Don't you actually want `value.split("-")`?

Comment: No , that code is a copy from another which has .split('[-.]*') I forgot to include the dot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation for re.split() error?](/q/40063797/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.6 you get the warning that this is going to happen:

> FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.

Since `[-]*` can match zero-length string, it does that in 3.7. You can prevent that by using something that doesn't. Either `-` or `-+` will do (depending on what you want to happen for `V--12345`.

If you don't care about the consecutive `-` signs, you can even do `value.split('-')` instead, without requiring `re`.